# How to add member to LDAP group from ansible task

Tags: ansible, ldap

Creating a "newuser" task in ansible, and one of the tasks is to add the newuser to a number of ldap groups. I'm getting a Invalid Syntax error, and it's not clear how or why my syntax is wrong (it seems to be a LDAP syntax issue, not python/ansible syntax).

I can use ldapmodify from the command line to add the member, but not the ansible task.

Example to successfully add from command line:

```sh
ldap="dn: cn=mygroup,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: cn=email@domain.com,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
"
echo "${ldap}" | /usr/bin/ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com -w mypass
modifying entry "cn=mygroup,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

Attempting to use ansible task:

```
   - name: Add to ldap groups as needed
     ldap_attr:
       dn: "cn=mygroup,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com"
       name: member
       values: "email@domain.com,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com"
       state: present
       params: "{{ ldap_auth }}"
```

The error from ansible is:
ldap.INVALID_SYNTAX: {'info': u'value does not conform to assertion syntax', 'desc': u'Invalid syntax'}

The ansible variable ldap_auth is defined as:
ldap_auth:
  server_uri: ldap://10.1.1.1
  bind_dn: "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com"
  bind_pw: "mypass"

I was expecting the user is added to the ldap group as an additional member.

ldapsearch shows this as one of my current groups:
dn: cn=mygroup,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: mygroup
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
description: My Group Users (Group Calendar)
member: cn=email1@domain.com,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
member: cn=email2@domain.com,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the LDAP modules, but the Ansible documentation says you need to use the `ldap_entry` module for new entries.

See [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ldap_attr_module.html#notes):

> Note
>   This only deals with attributes on existing entries. To add or remove whole entries, see ldap_entry.

Try the [`ldap_entry` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ldap_entry_module.html).

Comment: From what I can tell, I am adding an attribute to an existing entry. ie, the entry is the group, the attribute is an additional member in the group. Although I could be wrong here, but it also looks like this example: [link](https://yalis.fr/git/yves/home-server/src/branch/master/roles/slapd/tasks/main.yml) where they use: 

`  ldap_attr:
    dn: "cn={{item.group}},ou=Groups,{{ldap_root}}"
    name: memberuid
    values: "{{item.member}}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ldap_system_group_members}}"
`

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on the same use case as you. I think the only thing missing from your example is the *common name* element before the email address.

Try this and see if it works.

```
- name: Add to ldap groups as needed
  ldap_attr:
    dn: "cn=mygroup,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com"
    name: member
    values: "cn=email@domain.com,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com"     
    state: present
    params: "{{ ldap_auth }}"
```